# Javascript - Node.js - Socket.io multiple firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm creating a rochambo game with node.js and socket.io, like this :

A player makes a bet, that is sent to all players. Then, other players can select a sign a click on 'challenge'. But when they do, it emits the message a number of times that corresponds to the index of the bet on the server. I can't find out why.

I hope you understood me with my poor english... Thx!

Here is the code :

Server side :

```
socket.on('createbet', function (player, sign) {
var identifiant = socket.id;
    var gamenumber = RandomString(20);
    global[gamenumber] = new Array(identifiant,player,sign);
socket.broadcast.emit('newbet', gamenumber, player);
});

socket.on('challenge', function (gamenumber, cleacces, signe, screenname) {
     //This is where I realize that the event challenge is received multiple times
    });
```

Client side :

```
socket.on('newbet', function(gamenumber, player) {
   var imageElement = '<div class="'+gamenumber+'"><div>'+player+'</div><div><img class="signchoice'+gamenumber+'" src="images/unknown.png"/><input type="hidden" class="sign'+gamenumber+'" value="" /></div><div><input class="button" type="submit" value="Challenge!" /><input type="hidden" value="'+gamenumber+'"/></div>';
    $('#BetList').append(imageElement);
    $('.signchoice'+gamenumber).click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src') == 'images/ro.png'){$(this).attr('src','images/cham.png');$(this).next().val('cham');}
        else if ($(this).attr('src') == 'images/cham.png'){$(this).attr('src','images/bo.png');$(this).next().val('bo');}
        else {$(this).attr('src','images/ro.png');$(this).next().val('ro');}
    });
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var gamenumber = $(this).next().val();
        socket.emit('challenge', gamenumber, $('.sign'+numerodujeu).val(),$('#screenname').val());
    }); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this code:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  var gamenumber = $(this).next().val();
  socket.emit('challenge', gamenumber, $('.sign' +numerodujeu).val(),$('#screenname').val());
});
```

with this one:

```
$('.button').unbind('click').click(function() {
  var gamenumber = $(this).next().val();
  socket.emit('challenge', gamenumber, $('.sign' + gamenumber).val(), $('#screenname').val());
});
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that you bind the click event on `.button` multiple times (on each 'newbet' event).

Here is a live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rczjn

Hope it helps!